# how can I create Live Data in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-livedata

Im creating a sample app to study the MVVM android software architecture, but I can't find the guides for this in the xamarin.android docs.

I created the database and it's methods for the [ROOM], after that I created the entity.

then I got a problem creating the live data. I'm following an android tutorial (since I can't find a xamarin.android one)...

So my question is, is there a way to create live data in xamarin.android, and, if there is, how do I do it?

Comment: are you asking how you pre-populate the db with data for testing?

Comment: no I don't think that's it, for example, in android (java) I can do LiveData<List<Note>>, but I see no way of doing the same in xamarin (c#)

Comment: You can use `Observer` to do that.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: no, :/, I wish I had, but it looks like xamarin,android, doesnt implement the concept of live data, but I think I saw somewhere a library that implemented live data into xamarin.android

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out too.  I found a nuget package that provides an implementation. 
 The problem I'm having is that the LiveData class doesn't have a generic implementation LiveData<T> If I figure out what to do I'll post an actual answer. 
 Hope this helps you. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData/1.1.1.1?_src=template

Comment: Still haven't tried (since I moved on to another project since then) but you could try MvvmLight: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight